# Unable to retrieve SSIS Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis

I'm currently working on upgrading an SSIS project from SQL Server 2014 to SQL Server 2019. In this project, I've set up my database connection string to be retrieved from an XML file using the "script task" feature.

However, during the process of assigning values to the data, I've encountered an issue where `[Dts.Connections]` cannot locate the connection manager configured in the package. This problem seems to occur intermittently, making it highly unreliable.

I'm reaching out to the community to see if anyone has faced a similar issue and if so, could you please provide some guidance or solutions?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
Private Sub SetDBConnection(ByVal DataConnactionlist As List(Of DataConnectionInfo))
    For Each DBinfo As DataConnectionInfo In DataConnactionlist
        Dim DBName As String = DBinfo.Value
        If (Dts.Connections.Contains(DBName)) Then
            Dts.Connections.Item(DBName).ConnectionString = DBinfo.Key
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When an error occurs in the code segment `Dts.Connections.Item(DBName).ConnectionString`, the error is:

> The connection 'xxx' is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found

Methods already tested

1. Upgrading the package `TargetServerVersion` to SQL Server 2019
2. Adjusting the package's `DelayValidation=True` setting
3. Deploying to SQL Server Integration Services for testing

Comment: Please don't use images... show us the text...

Comment: Doing all that you probably already did this, but did you open up and recompile the script task itself?  I have had issues where upgrading SSIS and everything worked except some script tasks, those I had to open up, recompile, then upload to the server again and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for providing this suggestion. I've attempted to recompile all script tasks, but unfortunately, the errors still persist. This error occurs with a fifty percent chance. Once again, thank you for your response.